# Not able to apply percent conversion for column in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am currently getting an error while using the percentpipe to convert the values on column of ag-grid in my angular 7 application. The column in question is Percent column as you can see below in the column definition section in the code. Cat i use the percentpipe or is there another way of doing in ag-grid

The error that i get is

ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

Component code

```
import { formatDate, PercentPipe } from '@angular/common';

 export class AllocationsComponent implements OnInit {

    private Error: string;
    public evalDate: Date;
    private _evalDate: Date;
    public AllocationDetails: any;
    private _ManagerStrategyId: number;
    public GridOptions: GridOptions;
    windowHeight: any;
    offset: number;
    ngZone: any;
    router: any;
    Comparator: Comparator;
    Route: any;


   constructor(private allocationsService: AllocationsService, private comparator: Comparator,
                private zone: NgZone, private route: ActivatedRoute, private percentPipe: PercentPipe) {
        this.Comparator = comparator;
        this.Route = route;

        window.onresize = (e) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight - this.offset;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (!this.GridOptions || !this.GridOptions.api) {
                        return;
                    }
                    this.GridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                }, 500, true);
            });
        };
    }


 setGridOptions() {
        this.GridOptions = {
            columnDefs: this.getColumns(),
            rowData: this.AllocationDetails,
            enableFilter: true,
            enableColResize: true,
            animateRows: true,
            groupDefaultExpanded: 1,
            enableSorting: true,
            suppressCellSelection: true,

            onGridReady: e => {
                if (!e || !e.api) {
                    return;
                }
                e.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                this.setDefaultSortOrder();
            },
            getRowStyle: (params) => {
                if (params.node.level === 0) {
                    return { 'background-color': '#FCE7D7' };
                }
            },

            autoGroupColumnDef: {

                headerName: 'Manager Strategy', width: 300
            },
        };
    }


     private getColumns(): Array<any> {
        const self = this;
        const definition = [
            { headerName: 'Date', field: 'EvalDate', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm ID', field: 'FirmID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy ID', field: 'FirmName', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm', field: 'ManagerStrategyID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy', field: 'ManagerStrategyName' },
            { headerName: 'Fund ID', field: 'ManagerFundID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Fund', field: 'ManagerFundName' },
            { headerName: 'Portfolio', field: 'ProductName' },
            { headerName: 'As Of', field: 'EvalDate',   cellRenderer: (data) => {
                return data.value ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
             } },
            { headerName: 'EMV (USD)', field: 'UsdEmv',  valueFormatter: currencyFormatter },
            { headerName: 'Percent', field: 'GroupPercent' ,  valueFormatter: formatPercent},
          ];
            function currencyFormatter(params) {
            return '$' + formatNumber(params.value);
        }

        function formatNumber(number) {
            // this puts commas into the number eg 1000 goes to 1,000,
             return Math.floor(number).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
        }

        function formatPercent(number) {

             return this.percentPipe.transform(number);
        }


        return definition;
    }
}
```

UI - This is how my column looks like without applying any format

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The have resolved this by writing my own method 
Basically just multiply the number by 100 and round it to two decimal places . It’s as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I too went with the solution of value*100.
Here's some code for anyone googling...

```
cellRenderer: props => {
if (isNumeric(props.value)) return `${props.value * 100}%`;
},
```

**A follow-up question:**
Did you find a way to show the percentage 77% instead of 0.77 when in edit-mode?